# How to get recent tzdata onto old ubuntu versions

Tags: updates, timezone

I have a bunch of servers running 10.04 with the timezone set to Asia/Jerusalem that have all wrongly switched out of DST last night. My workstation running 13.04, however, has the correct time (for now).

Looking at the [package details](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata), it looks like only recent ubuntu versions get timezone updates, so my questions are:

1. Really? Timezone database updates do not get backported to supported ubuntu versions? It seems like a weird decision, so maybe I'm missing something.
2. What would be the recommended way to make sure older servers get tzdata updates?
3. <strike>It seems that even the latest tzdata package (2013d) still contains stale information, and would change out of DST a few weeks to early. http://www.ietf.org/timezones/data/asia seems to contain the latest update (2013-06-27), but I'm not sure how to turn that into a zoneinfo database. How should I approach fixing this?</strike>

**Update:** Somebody opened a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata/+bug/1222345).

Comment: Apparently, the problem is not restricted to 10.04, and not even to Ubuntu. http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ynet.co.il%2Farticles%2F0%2C7340%2CL-4426914%2C00.html

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the latest tzdata package does contain the correct timezone data. To install it manually, I did this:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tzdata/tzdata_2013d-1ubuntu1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i tzdata_2013d-1ubuntu1_all.deb
```

Comment: How would you update centos?

Comment: @YardenST I don't know much about CentOS, but googling for `tzdata rpm`, I found [this package](http://mirror.pac-12.org/6.4/updates/x86_64/Packages/tzdata-java-2013c-2.el6.noarch.rpm) from July, which hopefully is up-to-date enough.

Comment: Thanks for help, unfortunately it does not updated enough.

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 i was able to install the latest package this way: ```wget -O /tmp/tzdata.deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tzdata/tzdata_2021a-1ubuntu1_all.deb \
  && dpkg -i /tmp/tzdata.deb```